# Struts2 upgrade (2.0.11 to 2.3.4), issues with GWT

Tags: gwt, struts2, guice

I've been tasked with upgrading an application from Struts2 v2.0.11 to v2.3.4 due to a vulnerability.  I've successfully managed to handle the conflicts and upgrading of all the dependencies with the exception of what I think is GWT.  The version of GWT is currently sitting at 2.0.3.

My main issue is a 404 for something called '/apps/dispatch', which is referenced by:

```
serve("/apps/dispatch").with(StandardDispatchServiceServlet.class);
```

No compile issues, no runtime issues (other than the 404).

Without upgrading the Struts2 version the app runs as expected.  Any thoughts on why the Struts2 upgrade breaks the GWT functionality?

Comment: That looks more like Guice configuration to me. Is the Struts2 filter configured there as well? Is the Struts2 filter mapped to `/*`? Please include more of your configuration.

Comment: I figured it out and you (Steven) are correct about it being the Struts2 filter.  There were fairly major changes to Struts2 after 2.0.11 (next version is 2.1.6).  Struts2 started allowing by default .action and no extension.  So this was causing "/apps/dispatch" to be under struts control and not pass through (it also did that to the welcome page as well at root).  Once I locked down Struts2 to only .action extension (how it was built so there shouldn't be issues) everything worked.

Comment: There is also a new option to exclude certain URL patterns from being processed by Struts2: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8192169/454470